# Domain is currently unable to handle this request on a Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Whenever I try to access my app online I get the following error.

`[the-domain] is currently unable to handle this request.`

I'm currently lost and don't even know what the problem is I've replicated my local environment on my server and the problem still persists, probably something I'm missing.

Here is my current config.

- Laravel 5.7
- PHP 7.2.9

Heres the stack trace form laravel.log:

```
[2018-09-30 12:18:28] staging.ERROR: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\F$
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/avanzi/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\\Autoload\\includeFile('/var/www/invite...')
#1 [internal function]: Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader->loadClass('Illuminate\\\\Supp...')
#2 /var/www/avanzi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(22): spl_autoload_call('Illuminate\\\\Supp...')
#3 /var/www/avanzi/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): include('/var/www/invite...')
#4 /var/www/avanzi/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\\Autoload\\includeFile('/var/www/invite...')
#5 [internal function]: Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader->loadClass('Illuminate\\\\Data...')
#6 /var/www/avanzi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseServiceProvider.php(35): spl_autoload_call('Illuminate\\\\Data...')
#7 /var/www/avanzi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(572): Illuminate\\Database\\DatabaseServiceProvider->register()
#8 /var/www/avanzi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php(75): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->register(Object(Illumin$
#9 /var/www/avanzi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(548): Illuminate\\Foundation\\ProviderRepository->load(Array)
#10 /var/www/avanzi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/RegisterProviders.php(17): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->registerConfi$
#11 /var/www/avanzi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(206): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\RegisterProviders->bootstrap(O$
#12 /var/www/avanzi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(162): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#13 /var/www/avanzi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(146): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->bootstrap()
#14 /var/www/avanzi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Ob$
#15 /var/www/avanzi/public/index.php(58): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#16 {main}
"}
```

NB: This works perfectly fine in my local environment with the same PHP and Laravel version.

Answer (score 2):

So I finally got it figured out for my use case.
I had the right PHP version installed but haven't enabled the extensions required by Laravel yet, so to fix this I had to go to the php.ini file for my currently installed and active PHP version and enable those extensions, here is a list of the required PHP extensions for a Laravel 5.7 project.

- PHP >= 7.1.3
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- PDO PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension
- Tokenizer PHP Extension
- XML PHP Extension
- Ctype PHP Extension
- JSON PHP Extension

With all these extensions installed your PHP configuration should be good to go.